# Coding War and struggling with displaying cards played

Tags: java

I'm working on coding War in Java.  It works, except I'm having trouble printing out the cards played.  Right now I have this:

```
    for (int i=0; i<26; i++) {
        int p1Value = player1.flip().getRank();
        System.out.println("Player 1 plays the " + player1.flip().toString());
        int p2Value = player2.flip().getRank();
        System.out.println("Player 2 plays the " + player2.flip().toString());
        System.out.println("-------------------------------------");
        
        

        //compare card values & allots point to the higher one
        if(p1Value > p2Value) {
            player1.incrementScore();
            showMessageDialog(null, "Player 1 wins the round.");//alerts w
        }
        
        else if (p2Value > p1Value) {
            player2.incrementScore();
            showMessageDialog(null, "Player 2 wins the round.");
        }
        else {
            showMessageDialog(null, "It's a tie! No points awarded.");
        
        }
    }
```

Changing to this has caused it to it to run only 13 times instead of 26 (but works the 13 times).  Before I added the Sysouts, it worked fine 26 times, but just didn't print the cards played.  My best guess is that I'm using up a separate card each time I say that a player is flipping.  I tried to assign it to a variable hoping that would help, but it didn't.  Am I right?  How can I fix?  TIA

Prints play(Player 1 plays the ___ and Player 2 plays the ___) 13 times.  Then this error:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 out of bounds for length 0

```
at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBounds(Preconditions.java:64)

at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBoundsCheckIndex(Preconditions.java:70)

at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.checkIndex(Preconditions.java:266)

at java.base/java.util.Objects.checkIndex(Objects.java:359)

at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.remove(ArrayList.java:504)

at Players.flip(Players.java:48)

at War.main(War.java:32)
```

Comment: You are not showing the whole code of the loop.  Do you increment `i` inside the loop as well as at the top of the loop?

Comment: editted the question to include the whole loop

Comment: Please show what is actually printed

Comment: The stack trace suggests that the cards that each player has are managed in an array list. The flip method probably removes a card from the list every time. Since the error happens after the 13th loop pass, I suspect that there are 26 cards of which each player receives 13. If my guess is correct, the loop may only run until i <13 ...

Comment: They each have 26, because it worked before I added the sysout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because within your Sysout, you're calling `flip()` again. Store the result into a variable instead.

```java
var result = player1.flip();
int p1Value = result.getRank();
System.out.println("Player 1 plays the " + result.toString());
```

Comment: That's what I suspected.  I had tried to create a variable for it but it didn't help.  Tried the same thing again and it did.  I think I may have forgotten to change it to the 2 different players and cards.  Thanks!